# creating 3D race tracks with elevation

Tags: modeling, workflow, bezier-curves

I have a top view line of a race track and a height map like this: http://www.gpsies.com/map.do?fileId=nhpgbnphafassllb&language=en

Is it possible to create a curve of the track and plot the height map automatically on the track so I get a result like this:

[image: reference image of desired output]
 <sub>Image from [this](https://mattyhall.github.io/posts/2014-08-22-f1-track-models-pt-2.html) article</sub>

Comment: I've digg some and I've found only how to create terrain map from those information. Are you interested in it?

Answer (score 6):

There is an addon that allows you to do this, you can download it here:
[Import GPX](https://github.com/vvoovv/blender-gpx/wiki/Documentation). You will also need to download the `.gpx` file from [the website you linked in your question](http://www.gpsies.com/map.do?fileId=nhpgbnphafassllb&language=en) (select `Download as` > `GPX Track`).

1. Install the addon and activate it.

   [image: Install the addon]
2. Go to `File` > `Import` > `GPX (.gpx)`

   [image: Import menu]
3. Select the `.gpx` file you downloaded, make sure that `Use elevation for Z-coordinate` option is checked, and click`Import GPX`.

   [image: Import GPX]
4. It may seem that nothing was added to the scene but you'll notice a new object in the Outliner (with the same name as your `.gpx` file). You can't see it in the scene because the track is very big (it's 2 km wide). Unless you want to keep it the original size, select the object, press <kbd>N</kbd> to open `Properties panel`, and change scale to something like `0.005`. You should be able to see the whole track now. Apply the scale by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > `Scale`.

   [image: Set the scale]
5. Press <kbd>3</kbd> to view the track from the right side (ortho) and <kbd>Tab</kbd> to `Edit Mode`. Select all vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>) and extrude them (<kbd>E</kbd>) down on Z axis (<kbd>Z</kbd>).

   [image: Extrude the vertices]
6. Press <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Z</kbd> > <kbd>0</kbd> to align vertices on Z axis.

   [image: Align the vertices]
7. Go back to `Object Mode` (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), press <kbd>N</kbd> to open `Tool shelf` and enable smooth shading on the object.

   [image: Enable smooth shading]
8. Enable `Auto smooth` option in the `Object Data` panel, and set the `Angle` to `80°`.

   [image: Enable auto smooth]
9. Add `Solidify` modifier and set preferred `Thickness` (`3 cm` look nice).

   [image: Add solidify modifier]
10. Add a ground plane, add a white diffuse material to both the track and the ground plane, add lights to the scene (only sun lamp in my scene) - and render.

    [image: Render]